# Removing a DataTable from a DataSet causes an Invalid Cast Exception

Tags: c#, sorting, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I have some code that I'm using to attempt to force a sort on a pair of DataTables within a DataSet. The DataSet is used by some generic code to populate DataGridViews and is called by multiple points within the solution. Note that I cannot change any of the code that takes the DataSet and shows the DataTables in the DataGridViews. All I can do is setup the DataSet first and then pass that.

I have one DataSet with two tables, named "OBSSettlementPrice" and "BrokerSettlementPrice". The DataSet is called ResultsDs. My code is:

```
DataTable dtOBS;
DataTable dtBroker;

ResultsDs.Tables["OBSSettlementPrice"].DefaultView.Sort = "SettlementDate, Product, DeliveryMonth";
ResultsDs.Tables["BrokerSettlementPrice"].DefaultView.Sort = "BrokerName, SettlementDate, Product, DeliveryMonth";
dtO = ResultsDs.Tables["OBSSettlementPrice"].DefaultView.ToTable();
dtB = ResultsDs.Tables["BrokerSettlementPrice"].DefaultView.ToTable();
ResultsDs.Tables.Remove(ResultsDs.Tables["OBSSettlementPrice"]);
ResultsDs.Tables.Add(dtOBS);
ResultsDs.Tables.Remove(ResultsDs.Tables["BrokerSettlementPrice"]); // error occurs here
ResultsDs.Tables.Add(dtBroker);
```

The aim is to set the sort on the default view for each data table, create a view from that and turn it into an independent table. Then to replace each of the original tables with the new ones.

I get an error on the last but one line, where I'm removing the table BrokerSettlementPrice. The error is:

```
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'OBSSettlementPriceDataTable'.
```

Before the execution of that line there are two tables in ResultsDs.Tables. Afterwards, only OBSSettlementPrice is there.

Note that the solution uses a DataSet definition files (.xsd files), where the tables are called BrokerSettlementPrice and OBSSettlementPrice, so these are strongly-typed. How do I remove the old versions of the tables and replace them with the new ones?

Comment: Just remove the table with `ResultsDs.Tables.Remove("OBSSettlementPrice");` (or with `"BrokerSettlementPrice"`). The [DataTableCollection.Remove Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablecollection.remove) has an overload accepting a string.

Comment: We are talking about typed Datasets/DataTables here right? Never tried something like this but i expect problems if you replace a typed DataTable here like the "OBSSettlementPriceDataTable" with something that is just a simple DataTable.

Comment: @Oliver - thank you. This works. I've also used found a couple of methods to convert to and from strongly-type DataSets which I'm explicitly using to make things a little clearer. If you'd like to create an answer with this, I'll mark it as the solution when the system allows.

Comment: @Ralf - yes, you are correct, it's this. But I believe that strongly-typed datatables are sub-classes of DataTable so you should be able to chuck them around similarly. Oliver's point above is correct.

Comment: If i recall correct a typed dataset has typed properties for its tables so there is a property that returns an OBSSettlementPriceDataTable(presumably ResultsDs.OBSSettlementPrice)  while you have replaced it via the Tables with a simple DataTable. I would expect this to fail (but did not try). And typed TableAdapters if you have those presumably also want typed DataTables but it is no longer.

Comment: And yes the typed DataTables are derived from DataTable. But this should not help if the derived type is expected and not the base type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the table with `ResultsDs.Tables.Remove("OBSSettlementPrice");` (or with `"BrokerSettlementPrice"`).

The [DataTableCollection.Remove Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablecollection.remove) has an overload accepting a string.